# Does Swagger have the ability to support API change history, or is there an open-source library that does?

Tags: api, swagger, revision-history, swagger-2.0, api-doc

I am using Swagger Editor to generate YAML/JSON code that will display the details of my API in Swagger UI.

I would like for the consumers of my API to be able to view a revision history (ex. an added field, a field changed from 'optional' to 'required', etc) of the API document. Is this functionality supported by Swagger?

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible with [swagger-diff](https://github.com/civisanalytics/swagger-diff)

Comment: You should disclose that this is not a part of the actual product but a third party add on which is not really associated with Swagger at all. It also does not incorporate with Swagger, it is an independent Ruby tool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not supported, at least in swagger-ui itself

Answer (score 0):

While an interesting idea, this is a hard problem to solve. Please check out this feature request - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/233. Feel free to add comments and opinions to help push it forward.